# How to open a file Uri that is taken from ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT via Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, uri

My app requests an `android.net.Uri` from user via `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "fileName.txt");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_FILE);
```

Then it receives the Uri (in `onAtivityResult(...)`) and writes some text to it (via a `PrintWriter`).
At this stage, I can easily view the file in the file manager app, and open it via an appropriate app.

But I fail to open it from my own app via `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` with this approach:

```
Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
openFileIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "text/plain");
openFileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);  //Or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
openFileIntent = Intent.createChooser(openFileIntent, "Choose an app:");
startActivity(openFileIntent);
```

Any app that I choose shows an error message; something like:

> File Not Found

---

PS:
Athough not necessary, here is the procedure I do to get the file Uri and write to it.

First I get the Uri and persist the permission to access this Uri in the `onAtivityResult(...)`:

```
Uri fileUri = resultData.getData();
final int takeFlags = resultData.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(fileUri, takeFlags);
```

Then a `Writer` is created via this approach:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd  = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(pfd.getFileDescriptor()) );
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
```

Finally, after writing some text to the file, I close the stream:

```
writer.close();
pfd.close();
```

Comment: With `takeFlags`, get rid of `resultData.getFlags() &`, as that's wrong and unnecessary. Just to confirm, the `fileUri` in your `ACTION_VIEW` is the same `fileUri` from your later code snippets?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, that is the same uri taken from the user.

Comment: What you have seems fine; there may be a bug in the app that you are starting. Is there anything interesting in Logcat from the other app when you start it this way?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think the problem is the 3rd party app. First because none of the apps in the "chooser" dialog can open the file. Second, I can open the file with all those apps from my file manager. Third, even if I delete the "createChooser" line to let the system choose the default app, nothing happens.

Comment: "Second, I can open the file with all those apps from my file manager" -- that may be a different `Uri` structure. I still recommend examining Logcat to see if you can learn something from error messages that the other apps might log. You could also create your own app that responds to `ACTION_VIEW` for that MIME type and `content` and see what you get, can you read in the contents, etc.

Comment: No, I couldn't find anything useful in the Logcat. I should note that those apps don't crash, they just cannot find the file. It is also worth noting that it is a simpe text file; nothing unsual. My best guess is there is sth wrong with my Uri. Is there an easy way that I can retrieve the Uri of the file again (which is in an arbitrary folder in the shared storage) without user iteraction?

Comment: "Is there an easy way that I can retrieve the Uri of the file again (which is in an arbitrary folder in the shared storage) without user iteraction?" -- not only is there no "easy" way, there is no way at all.